# Python Flask give argument to url

Tags: python, html, flask

How can I pass the id of my event object.

```
 <div class="row">
     {% for event in events %}
    <div class="col">
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img src="https://tailwindcss.com/img/card-top.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{event['title']}}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">{{event['description']}}</p>
      <h10 class="card-title">Start date: {{event['date']}}</h10>
    <a href="/participate/{event['id']}" class="btn btn-primary">Participate</a>
  </div>
</div>

    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

With my python code i try to get the id from the button.
My python code:

```
@app.route("/participate/<id>")
def participate(id):
    if session.get("email"):
        print(id)
        mail = setupMail()


        return redirect(url_for("home"))
    else: return redirect(url_for("login"))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote

```
{event["id"]}
```

with only one curly bracket. Try

```
{{event["id"}}
```

at your button instead, and replace the print statement in your python code by

```
app.logger.root.warning(id)
```

(print doesn’t work in flask)